# Navigation title disappears after use of custom back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have 3 pages

> - Page 1: Menu
> - Page 2: Menu > Navigation Controller > Map listview
> - Page 3: Menu > Navigation Controller > Map

It's possible to switch between page 2 and 3 but when you click "Back" it always goes to page 1 and I did this using  a custom back button.

After having used the custom back button once the following problem appears:
When I go to page 2 or 3 from the Menu page (Page 1) the navigation title appears and in less than a second it disappears. How is this possible?

These are the functions I am using:

```
private func hideAndAddNewBackButton(){
    if backToRoot{
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
        self.title = "Locaties"
    }
}

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let viewController2 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as? ViewController2{
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController2, animated: true);
    }
}

func needBackToRoot(){
    backToRoot = true;
}
```

And this is in my viewDidLoad():

```
var backToRoot:Bool = false;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideAndAddNewBackButton();
}
```

My switch button:

```
@IBAction func showLijst(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let viewController3 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Lijst") as? KaartListview{
        viewController3.needBackToRoot();
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController3, animated: true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was creating custom back button and setting in pushed controller 
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
    My solutions is :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "SomeTitle"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before and I fixed by using:

```
navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` function

Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Did you put it in the viewController that was missing the navBar? Also, have you checked in the storyBoard that the view controller os showing the navBar?

Comment: Yes it's visible in the storyboard and I am also sure that it's in the right viewcontroller. What I did notice is that it does work when I use the custom button on Page 2 but not when I use the one on Page 3

Comment: By page 3 you mean your viewController #3 right? If so, add the `navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false` in the `viewDidLoad()`, if you already did that and it didn't work, try doing it in the `viewWillAppear()`. That's all I can think of right now.

Comment: The problem was that I was using a navigation controller inbetween the menu and the other pages... My bad for not informing this.